# MySql: How to read a table from one database while searching second database table per each row?

Tags: mysql, database, search, join

I am new to MySql/PHP.

Each row from Database1.table1 has to be read and display. It contains a column which has search term that I need to pass on to Database2.table2 and process the returns per each row read. Currently I am making new connection to Database2.table2 for each row in db1.table1 which is really slow and inefficient. I can not change the table structures.

Thanks!

**tables**

db1 table1:

```
id_row    type        model        har               status    id         date         
1         ATX         Hybrion      88-85-5d-id-ss    y         aaa12345   2011/08/12
2         BTX         Savin        none              n         aaa12345   2010/04/05
3         Full        Hp           44-55-sd-qw-54    y         ashley a   2011/07/25
4         ATX         Delin        none              _         smith bon  2011/04/05
```

db2 table2:

```
id_row    id          first_name   last_name    dept    telephone
1         aaa12345    joe          smith        ANS     800 555 5555
2         bbb67890    sarah        brown        ITL     800 848 8848
```

So the database 1 table 1 is the one that gets read and displayed, db2 table2 is read and info displayed if ID is positive match. ID is only unique in the db2 table2, db1 table1 one has multi format column so it could or could not be an ID as well as those rows could have duplicate ID. Hope this gives better understanding of what i need. Thanks again!

Someone suggested to use `EXISTS` but I don't know how, given the situation.

Comment: First of all, make a connection to DB2 *and keep it open.* Secondly, make sure that `id` in DB2 is *indexed*, since you are accessing it in semi-random order.

Comment: My first reaction was "don't close it." You have told us nothing of your environment--OS, language, DB library being used, what servers the DBs are on--so I don't know how to begin to answer this question.

Comment: @peter: Server version: 5.0.26, using php to connect to server like `mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password) or die("Could not connect to the MySQL Server. Error: ". mysql_error());` then to database like `mysql_select_db($db_table) or die("Could not open Hartford Database. Error: ". mysql_error());` there are two separate files like that main file uses via `require 'db1.php'; require 'db2.php';` at the beginning of the script, from there everything is using variables for reference like $table.column and $db1.$table1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the user you're running as has the correct rights to see both databases, then you should be able to do this by joining the tables using the 'dbname.tablename' syntax like this:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from database1.table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN database2.table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

this will give you all rows from table A, and where there is a matching row in table b, the matching rows from there as well (or nulls if there is no matching row)..

Comment: @Andrey : this is the full query i have `SELECT $table.*, $table2.* FROM $db1.$table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN $db2.table2 ON $table1.id = $table2.id ORDER BY $table1.$sortbyme $o LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage`

Comment: @Tumharyyaaden: t1 and t2 are just aliases for table1 and table2.. You only need 1 connection to either db1 or db2. The user you're connected as needs to have permissions on the other db as well. The database will take care of connecting to the other db for you. the error message you got suggests that your user doesn't have permissions on db1..

Comment: @Tumharyyaaden: I guessed you probably did.. but I meant the username you're connecting with, not you yourself. Assume you're connecting to db1 as user1. The easiest way is to grant user1 access to select from tables in db2. Then use the syntax above. If you dont have the ability to do this, then you need to do something similar to what you're doing now, in which case you might find it quicker to perform the join yourself in your code rather than querying db2 1 row at a time

Comment: @StevieG: It's still not working for me but u r on the money about the method. So thanks.